# Htaccess and slash

Tags: .htaccess

i need to rewrite multiple urls with htaccess :

```
tuto.php -> https://example.com/tuto/

tuto.php?c=book -> https://example.com/tuto/book

tuto.php?c=book&s0=sub0&s1=sub1 -> https://example.com/tuto/book/sub0-to-sub1
```

Thank you .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am attempting to help you with `https://example.com/tuto/book/sub0-to-sub1` rest you can try yourself or find by googling they are not difficult.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ $1.php [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ $1.php?c=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/(.+)\-to\-(.+)$ $1.php?c=$2&s0=$3&s1=$4 [L]
```

Comment: Thank you, i've already  made research but always failed when implementing rewrite rule

Comment: RewriteRule ^tuto$  /tuto.php [L]   RewriteRule ^tuto/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ tuto.php?c=$1 [L]  maybe some rules in my htaccess before and after affect the result

Comment: Above should've worked nonetheless try with my above rules I am writing it all together.

Comment: It works ! thanks,  to avoid duplicate content do i need to add on each line [L,R=301] ?

Comment: Do not R=301, L flag is enough and also you can mark as accepted if it works for you it will help others.